# syntax error at line 354 : `=~' unexpected in hp unix

Tags: unix, ksh, hp-ux

my code is somehow like-

```
if [[ ! $FIRST=~ ^/ ]] then
            FIRST="${SECOND}/${FIRST}"
fi
```

and i am getting below error while running the script in HP UNIX-
syntax error at line 354 : `=~' unexpected.
It seems to work fine in linux.
Does anybody has any solution for it?

Comment: Perhaps you need a space before `=`?  Are you using ksh on Linux too?

Comment: Looks to me like a Bash-only construct. Do you have Bash available on the HP-UX system? What's on the script's shebang line?

Comment: There is no `=~` in ksh (and HP-UX is not Linux).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, the ksh on HP-UX is probably pretty old, so there's no `=~` operator.

However, you're just checking that the value begins with a slash, so use glob-style pattern matching:

```
if [[ $FIRST != /* ]]; then FIRST="$SECOND/$FIRST"; fi
```

If *that* doesn't work, use `case`:

```
case "$FIRST" in
    /*) : ;;
    *)  FIRST="$SECOND/$FIRST" ;;
esac
```